# When user is logged in, directly show main activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want that if a user is already logged in, another activity is loaded and displayed. All in all, it all works. The only problem is that I get to see the SignIn Activity for about 2 seconds instead of the MainActivity directly. How can I change this behavior?

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    auth = Firebase.auth
    userAlreadyLoggedIn()

    //Is shown for 2seconds
    binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)   
  }



    private fun userAlreadyLoggedIn(){        
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    if(currentUser != null){
        var db:FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val userRef = db.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USER).document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)

        userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {document ->
            if(document !== null)
            {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        
      }
   }
```

Comment: Instead of check isUserLoggedIn control inside activity and navigate to other activity, build an one activity - multiple fragment structure and set up jetpack navigation. You can set start destination inside owner activity and initialize the necessary fragment. this approach better and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

Because you call start MainActivity in SignInActivity, so it will always run onCreate of SignInActivity, then start MainActivity.

You should have a SplashActivity, in that, check user is logged in or not.
If user logged in, show MainActivity else show SignInActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try if below code works:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        userAlreadyLoggedIn()  
    }

    private fun userAlreadyLoggedIn(){        
        val currentUserID = getCurrentUserID()
            if (currentUserID.isNotEmpty()) {
                startActivity(Intent(this@SignInActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            } else {
                  // Do something if log in fails.
            }
    }

    fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }
        return currentUserID
    }
```